# Do we have any generic script / jquery plugin to apply javascript on the content loaded through ajax tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need ajax tabs and a jquery slider for the second tab.

ISSUE:
If the content is not loaded through ajax everything works fine but to ajax content scripts are not applicable.

REQUIREMENT:
As I am using ajax in most of places, is there any generic script / plugin which will help me to overcome this problem in general?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you have to initialise the slider after you load it using ajax.

```
$('.tab').html(data.returns);
//after that initialise slider.. should work
```